# Does Guardian of Nature in Great Tree form combined with Shillelagh give advantage for quarterstaff attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, ability-scores

If a druid wields a quarterstaff and casts [*shillelagh*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shillelagh) and afterwards casts [*guardian of nature*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/guardian-of-nature), do the quarterstaff attacks count as Wisdom-based, so that the druid has advantage with them?

---

### Shillelagh

> For the duration, you can use your spellcasting ability instead of Strength for the attack and damage rolls of melee attacks using that weapon, ...

### Guardian of Nature (in Great Tree form)

> - You make Dexterity- and Wisdom-based attack rolls with advantage.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Yes

Shillelagh does indeed make your weapon attacks Wisdom-based if you are a druid:

> For the duration, you can use your spellcasting ability instead of Strength for a club or quarterstaff you touch.

Usually melee weapon attacks are Strength-based but the spell changes them to use your spellcasting ability which is Wisdom for druids.